# Excel does not get the Structured Reference when i manually select it, but references do exist

Tags: excel, vba, structured-references

Good day, yesterday the workbook worked just fine, today the Structured Reference in any object doesn't work, in example picture 1 I select with the mouse or arrow keys "E2", and it doesn't get the Table name nor reference, but if I write the name of the table or reference it shows (I must add the "use reference" option is enabled.

[image]

[image]

Tried unable save close and re-enable then save close again, not working sadly).

The workbook behaves the same if saved as a no-macro file, a binary or a non-xml file, this does not happen with other workbooks in the same PC, tried opening in other PC and same behaviour.

Is there something i can try?

Comment: File >> Options >> Formulas >> Use Table Names in Formulas ?

Comment: It was enabled, i tried unchecking it, saveing close and reopen, then check it save, close and reopen, no luck.

Comment: Maybe you have converted this 'table' to a range and `Table1` is showing because you have a table named `Table1` in another worksheet.